# Add reverse log transformation to binned scale on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some constraints for my plot:

- `x` axis should be reversed and logarithmic
- `y` axis should be binned, but:

  - bins should be displayed in reverse order
  - bins size should have logarithmic scale or something similar (`0-10` bin should be bigger than `10-20`, and so on)
- For both `x` and `y`, `0` tick should appear on the axis (which we usually achieve with `limits=c(0, 0)`)

Here is some sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(
    a=sample(seq(0, 100), 1e4, replace=TRUE), 
    b=sample(1e6, 1e4), 
    t=sample(letters[seq(2)], 1e4, replace=TRUE)
)
```

I can achieve most constraints on `x` axis, and some on `y`:

```
dat |> ggplot(aes(y=a, x=b, colour=t)) + 
    geom_jitter() + 
    scale_x_continuous(
        trans=c("log10", "reverse"), 
        breaks=seq(0, 6) |> purrr::map(~c(2.5, 5, 10)*10^.x) |> unlist(), 
        expand=c(0, 0)
    ) + 
    scale_y_binned(expand=c(0, 0), limits=c(0, 100)) +
    ggthemes::theme_clean()
```

[image]

What's missing here is:

- 0 tick on `x`: using `limits=c(0, 100)` with `log` scale produces an error. Using `scales::pseudo_log_trans` instead of `scales::log10` doesn't work. I tried to use `ggallin::pseudolog10_trans` that also keeps 0 and negatives, but couldn't figure how to mix it with another transformer.
- log scale on `y` axis. The issue here is that `scale_y_binned` discretizes the data, and log transformation can only be applied to continuous data.
- reversed `y` axis. The issue here is similar, because reversing an axis is not just a cosmetic operation for `ggplot2` like `coord_flip` would be; it is actually also a transformation that requires continuous data.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to do this is to bin the scale manually and use a continuous rather than binned y scale with custom labels:

```r
dat |>
  within(abin <- cut(a, c(0, 10^seq(0, 2, 0.25)), include.lowest = TRUE,
                     right = FALSE, 
                     labels = seq(-0.1072541, by = 0.25, len = 9)))|>
  within(abin <- as.numeric(as.character(abin))) |>
  ggplot(aes(y = abin, x = log10(b + 1), colour = t)) + 
  geom_jitter() + 
  scale_x_reverse(breaks = c(log10(c(5e5, 25e4, 1e5, 5e4, 25e3, 1e4, 5e3,
                                   25e2, 1e3, 5e2, 250, 100, 50, 10)+1), 0.3),
                  limits = c(6, 0.3), expand = c(0, 0), name = "b",
                  labels = ~c(head(comma(10^(.x) - 1), -1), 0)) + 
  scale_y_reverse('a', breaks = seq(-0.25, 2, 0.25),
                  labels = ~ c(0, round(10^(tail(.x, -1))))) +
  ggthemes::theme_clean()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I can definitely build up on this. If you have any lead on the "display 0 tick on both axis" thing, I will more than happily accept your answer.

Comment: I just saw your edit. Just perfect. Thanks!